# How to Search lxml after a keyword using python

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a web scraper, that is scraping pages with many sections of information using bs4. Since a lot of the sections repeat `div class` ' s it is hard to scrape. I am trying to find a way to get it to start searching the lxml after a specific phrase in the html. is there a way to do this?

below is a small sample of what I am working with, trying to get something like `table_soup` to start after a specific phrase.

````
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import re

# Making get request
r = requests.get('https://m.the-numbers.com/movie/Black-Panther')

# Creating BeautifulSoup object
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

# Localizing table from the BS object
table_soup = soup.find('div', class_='row').find('div', class_='table-responsive').find('table', id='movie_finances')
website = 'https://m.the-numbers.com/'


# Iterating through all trs in the table except the first(header) and the last two(summary) rows 
for tr in table_soup.find_all('tr')[1:6]:
    tds = tr.find_all('td')
    title = tds[0].text.strip()

    # make sure that home market performance doesnt check the second one
    if title != 'Home Market Performance':
        details.append({
            'title': title,
            'amount': tds[1].text.strip(),
        })

summary_soup = soup.find('div', id='summary').find('div', class_='table-responsive').find('table', class_='table table-sm')
summaryList = []
for tr in summary_soup.find_all('tr')[1:4]:
    tdmd = tr.find_all('td')

    summaryList.append({
        'unit': tdmd[1].text.strip(),
    })```
````

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv
import re

r = requests.get('https://m.the-numbers.com/movie/Black-Panther')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
# If you have an unique id for the table you can directly access the table using that id
table_soup = soup.find('table', id='movie_finances')
table_soup.find_all('tr')
# this will get the 4 tr tags in the body. No need to use slicing.

summary_soup = soup.find('div',id="summary").find('div').find_all('div')[3].find('table')
```

#### as 'td' tag which is a child with the text find it and get the parent to access both title and value

```
prod_budget_tag, value_tag = summary_soup.find('td', text=u"Production\xa0Budget:").find_parent('tr').find_all('td')

print prod_budget_tag.text, value_tag.text
```

Similarly you can get other fields and values from the table

Comment: Sorry, might be confusing how I presented it, so this is just a section, example of what I am using. I would like to pull the data from "Movie Details" section, I am using this currently, trying to fix it:

```summary_soup = soup.find('div', id='summary').find('div', class_='table-responsive').find('table', class_='table table-sm')
summaryList = []
for tr in summary_soup.find_all('tr')[1:4]:
    tdmd = tr.find_all('td')
    
    summaryList.append({
        'unit': tdmd[1].text.strip(),
    })```